# Adobe Flash CS5, timeline and multiple windows

Tags: adobe-flash, timeline

I am using Adobe Flash Professional CS5 and I need to open two windows of my scene, each with different zoom, which I did without any trouble.

The problem is following: I need Timeline to switch BOTH windows to the frame I choose, not only the active window, so that I can see how my scene works in both windows at the same time.

Shortly, how can I sync frame selection in two windows?